# Create swatch colours as links in wordpress

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to replicate a drop down menu that I have seen on a few websites.

For example - https://www.johnelliott.co/products/ls-classic-curve-tee-mustard

Each variation in the colour menu is its own link that redirects the user to the URL of that product colour. The selected colour is also displayed at the top of the menu.

I have tried to look at the source code but I just don't understand how I am meant to implement it or create something similar for my wordpress site.